# DataTable and Bootstrap 4.2.1 formating Show entries and Search

Tags: css, datatable, datatables, bootstrap-4

I can't get the format to display like the example on the [DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html) website.

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
<link href="assets/plugins/DataTables-1.10.18/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/DataTables-1.10.18/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/DataTables-1.10.18/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

$(function($) {
  $('#myTbl').DataTable();
});
```

Here is my result.

[image]

I want it to look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

may you need [dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)

example:

```
$('#myTbl').DataTable({dom: "<'row gridheader'<'col-sm-12 col-md-12'B>>"
    + "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>"
    + "<'row gridfooter'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>"});
```

Comment: Hi Wilmer, thanks for your suggestion. Sadly, it removed the entire header. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something has screwed `<label>` element styling with something like `{width: 50px; display: block}`. You may need to check whether your stylesheets, loaded after `dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css` may override `<label>` styling or, maybe, you did something, like `$('label').css({'width': '50px'; 'display': 'block'})` within your code.

So, you might need to limit the scope of your 'label' selector within stylesheets or code. Or, if CSS is the case, change the order of loading your stylesheets, so that default styles are not getting overwritten.

Comment: Thanks for your response ygorbunkov, I'll try it tonight and let you you how it goes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the default datatables.net CSS. Use the one specifically for Bootstrap 4 and this will work fine.